# JS Выделение одного из нескольких элементов с помощью toggleClass

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть три элемента, при нажатии на один из них он выделяется, а другие нет.
Реализовал через `toggleClass`. Как сделать так, что бы при повторном нажатии на выделенный элемент, он  переставал быть выделенным.

```js
$('.el').click(function(){
                              $('.el').removeClass('active');                             $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.el img{
 border: 50px solid;
 border-radius: 100%;
}
.active img{
 border: 50px solid bisque;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el"><img src=""></div>
<div class="el"><img src=""></div>
<div class="el"><img src=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пока писал вопрос в голову пришло такое решение, может можно как то более элегантно сделать?)

```js
$('.el').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $('.el').removeClass('active');
   } else {$('.el').removeClass('active'); $(this).toggleClass('active');}
});
```

```css
.el img{
border: 50px solid;
border-radius: 100%;
}
.active img{
border: 50px solid bisque;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el"><img src=""></div>
<div class="el"><img src=""></div>
<div class="el"><img src=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.el').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $('.el').removeClass('active');
   } else {$('.el').addClass('active');}
});
```

А если попроизводительнее и без монструозных скриптов -

css:

```
input {display:none;}
label {...styles for label...}
input:checked + label {...styles for selected label...}
```

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="block1"/>
<label for="block1">...</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="block2"/>
<label for="block2">...</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="block3"/>
<label for="block3">...</label>
```